# EmailAddressAtribute ignored

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I have a class which defines the property `EmailAddress` with the attribute `EmailAddressAttribute` from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public ICollection<ValidationResult> Validate()
    {
        ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), results);
        return results;
    }
}
```

When I set the value of `EmailAddress` to be an invalid email (e.g. 'test123'), the `Validate()` method tells me the entity is valid.

The `RequiredAttribute` validation is working (e.g. setting `Name` to `null` shows me a validation error).

How do I get `EmailAddressAttribute` working in my validator?

Comment: Are you using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`?

Comment: Yes - apologies, I should have put that in the question.

Comment: Could you try adding the following `[Required][DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)][EmailAddress]public string EmailAddress { get; set; }`

Comment: Done - no difference in functionality

Comment: I can't see any immediate error, my guess was that it was missing `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` and silently wouldn't do anything. Is .NET framework 4.5?

Comment: did you add nuGet package DataAnnotationsExtensions?

Comment: Yeah, .net 4.5. I haven't added the extensions package.

Answer (score 7):

After playing with the overloads available for each method, I found the following overload which includes a parameter called `validateAllProeprties`.

When this is set to `true` the object is property validated.

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), results, true);
```

I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to validate all properties, but having this set to `false` or not set (defaults to `false`) will only validate required attributes.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx) explains.

Answer (score 1):

to use Validation with the Data Annotation Validators you should add both references to 
`Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly and the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly.

then you need to register the DataAnnotations Model Binder in the Global.asax file. Add the following line of code to the `Application_Start()` event handler so that the `Application_Start()` method looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder();
}
```

after that you have registered the `dataAnnotationsModelBinder` as the default model binder for the entire ASP.NET MVC application

then your code should work properly

```
public class User : Entity
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

refer [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs) for documentation

Comment: Thanks faby. I shall give this a go. I'm not using mvc though (just data annotations). Will report back :-)

Comment: @Darbio I'm sorry that my solution didn't help you. I've seen that you have solved your problem that is the principal goal! Well done.